# fail to load server data on FF an IE only

Tags: javascript, asp.net, facebook, facebook-like

I don't plan you'll debug it, but maybe you could see in a moment:
I wrote a simple page that shows "running messages".

However it works for Chrome only (not FF or IE)
http://hydepark.apphb.com/display.aspx
I see this is a server side issue, but it doesn't make sense as it's browser dependant.

You have an idea?

```
    var msgsList = [{"Guid":"c281e6ec-acdc-4c35-80ee-12c9ba1ab95e","Author":"2","Content":"222","Email":"22","CreationDate":"\/Date(1321389457043)\/","Rating":0,"Path":"D:\\websites\\b1\\08c47\\4f839e3\\_PublishedWebsites\\TB.Site\\c281e6ec-acdc-4c35-80ee-12c9ba1ab95e.html"},{"Guid":"58aaa80d-f09e-439a-bec6-60b090f39c26","Author":"1","Content":"111","Email":"11","CreationDate":"\/Date(1321389451653)\/","Rating":0,"Path":"D:\\websites\\b1\\08c47\\4f839e3\\_PublishedWebsites\\TB.Site\\58aaa80d-f09e-439a-bec6-60b090f39c26.html"}];
    var pagePath = window.location.pathname;

    //parses the list
    $(document).ready(function ()
    {
    parseList = function(pos,list)
    {   
    if  (pos < list.length)
    {
            var obj = list[pos];
            TextArea1.value = obj.Content;
            Author.value = obj.Author;
        var newHeading = encodeURIComponent( window.location.href +"?id="+ obj.Guid );
        var likeFrame = $('.fb-like iframe');

        //var likeFrame = $('iframe.fb_ltr')[0];
        var newHref = 'href=' + newHeading + '&layout=';
        var newSrc = likeFrame.attr('src').replace(/href=.+&layout=/, newHref);
        likeFrame.attr('src', newSrc);

            setTimeout(function(){parseList(++pos,list);}, 5000);
    }
    else
        {
        //PageMethod('RefillMessages', [], AjaxSucceeded, AjaxFailed);
         WebMethod('RefillMessages', [], AjaxSucceeded, AjaxFailed);
        }
    }

    setTimeout(function(){parseList(0,msgsList);}, 2000);
    //parseList(0,msgsList);
    });
```

Comment: Fails [basic automated qa](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fhydepark.apphb.com%2Fdisplay.aspx&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0). Don't depend on browser error recovery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
TextArea1.value = obj.Content;
```

You should never just reference an element by its id. Some browsers will support this for old old >10 years ago way of coding.

```
document.getElementById("TextArea1").value = obj.Content;
```

Comment: Tried once again, but get 2 fb-likes and fb error. Could you review?

Answer (score 0):

If you open Firebug on Firefox, you will see that `TextArea1` is undefined.

It looks Chrome is considering it as a global variable, while FF not.

An easy way to read forms is to get it by and id, and read the field with their name, eg:

```
var frm = document.getElementById('form1');
//then get it by frm.TextArea1.value
```